# Why sudo env is not showing all the environment variables?

Tags: bash, sudo, environment-variables

I have a variable set in a script file in /etc/profile.d/somescript.sh
I have modified the /etc/sudoers and added "ansible" user to the sudoers file like this:

```
Defaults !env_reset
ansible    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:   ALL
```

Why isn't the first line outputting anything ? why "sudo env" is not showing all environment variables (only partial)?

```
[ansible@ACEPP-LM-01 ~]$ sudo env | grep ENV
[ansible@ACEPP-LM-01 ~]$ sudo echo $ENV
PP
[ansible@ACEPP-LM-01 ~]$ echo $ENV
PP
[ansible@ACEPP-LM-01 ~]$ env | grep ENV
ENV=PP
```

Solution for what I need is putting an 
    alias sudo="sudo -i"
in ~/.bashrc of root and also the user ansible.

Comment: When `ENV` contains a file path, it is used by some old shells as the path of a file sourced on startup (also in POSIX shells, but only when interactive). So it's one of those that sudo always blacklists to avoid users bypassing the sudo policies (even with `!env_reset`).

Comment: `ENV=`hostname | awk -F- '{print $1}' | sed 's/ACE//'`` - no path

Comment: Note that when you run `sudo echo $ENV`, that is not actually an indication that `$ENV` is set in the sudo environment. The variable is expanded by your shell _before_ it runs `sudo`.

Comment: setting the file with the variables like : Defaults:user env_file=/path/to/file/to/be/sourced is not doing the substitutions

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Your comment should be an answer!

Comment: @Gilles !env_reset does not do variable substitution like A=$B. The best solution is `sudo -i`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `-E` parameter on `sudo`:

```
-E, --preserve-env
             Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to pre‐
             serve their existing environment variables.  The security
             policy may return an error if the user does not have permis‐
             sion to preserve the environment.
```

Comment: I want sudo to use -E or -i by default

Comment: That won't work. `ENV` like other dangerous environment variables (`PS4`, `BASHOPTS`, `BASH_ENV`, `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`, `PYTHONPATH`...) is always blacklisted. It also overwrites a number of env vars and sanitises many, and blacklists based on content as well (like the ones starting with `()` for bash exported functions). You'd need to add `Defaults env_keep = "*"` to override that.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier if I put all my variables in ~/.bashrc ? This way sudo will see them no matter what ?

Comment: no, that will not work. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228441/261934